# Walrus assignment expression in list comprehension/generator

Tags: python

I am trying to pass each element of `foo_list` into a function `expensive_call`, and get a list of all the items whose output of `expensive_call` is Truthy. I am trying to do it with list comprehensions, is it possible? Something like:

Something like this:

```
 result_list = [y := expensive_call(x) for x in foo_list if y]
```

or....

```
 result_list = [y for x in foo_list if y := expensive_call(x)]
```

Note: This is not a solution because it call expensive call twice:

```
 result_list = [expensive_call(x) for x in foo_list if expensive_call(x)]
```

And before someone recommends none list comprehension, I know one can do:

```
result_list = []
for x in foo_list:
   result = expensive_call(x)
   result and result_list.append(result)
```

Comment: "a list of all the *items whose output* of expensive_call is Truthy." Wait, doesn't that mean you want the result to contain original elements from the input? Isn't that just `[x for x in foo_list if expensive_call(x)]`? What's the difficulty? (That corresponds to the code in your non-comprehension version, too.)

Comment: What is wrong with your second version?  Did you try it?

Comment: How about: `[y for y in map(expensive_call,foo_list) if y]`

Comment: In your loop version, avoid cutesy things like `result and result_list.append(x)`, use `if result: result_list.append(x)`, idiomatic Python values *clarity and being explicit*, not brevity

Comment: You might want to edit your loop variation, because it is different logic than the others.  You clearly wanted the last  line: `result and result_list.append(result)`.  Though as @juanpa.arrivillaga says, that's "cutesy" and could mislead many.

Comment: Note, before assignment expressions, the way to do this is `[y for x in data for y in [expensive_call(x)] if y]`, this was such a common idiom that there is a bytecode optimization that actually doesn't create a list `[expensive_call(x)]` and just assigns the result of `expensive_call(x)`  to a local variable `y`. Personally, I would just use a regular loop, though.

Comment: I hope this question doesn't get closed, because I think there's good information here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting from above:

> result_list = [y for x in foo_list if y := expensive_call(x)]

It should work almost exactly as how you have it; just remember to parenthesize the assignment with the `:=` operator, as shown below.

```py
foo_list = [1, 2, 3]
def check(x): return x if x != 2 else None

result_list = [y for x in foo_list if (y := check(x))]
print(result_list)
```

Result:

```
[1, 3]
```

Comment: Does it fail without the parentheses?

Comment: Yep, definitely seems to fail for me; at least when I test with a Python 3.9 environment.

Comment: Interesting.   I wonder how it parses.

Comment: From the PEP on the walrus operator, it looks like there are edge cases where the `()` are required around the expression; tbh I'm not sure why it's needed here though.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by [RufusVS](https://stackoverflow.com/users/925592/rufusvs), this works and has the expected complexity.

```
def expensive_call(x):
    return x == 5

foo_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,6,5]
print([y for y in map(expensive_call,foo_list) if y])
```

results in

```
[True, True]
```

As there are two 5 that satisfy `expensive_call`

Answer (score 0):

You want to check if `expensive_call(x)` is Truthy, and if so append it to the list? Something like this should work. Doesn't need to use a walrus op:

```
[x for x in foo_list if expensive_call(x)]
```

If you want to store the output of `expensive_call(x)` and not x then your second approach needs parentheses around the walrus assignment due to how the assignment operator works. Refer to [PEP 572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/#id10) for more info.

```
[y for x in foo_list if (y := expensive_call(x))]
```

Comment: The OP wants to save the result of the call, not the argument.  AFAICT

Comment: @RufusVS if you refer to OP's non-comprehension they use `result_list.append(x)` not `result_list.append(result)` and they said they want to store the item if the output of the func is truthy not store the ouput of the func if it's truthy.

Comment: I did not even read the loop version he posted.  Clearly it's not the same logic as his other attempts, but now I see where you were coming from.

Comment: Sorry for causing confusion, I corrected my code, thank you!